# With a text input (name of a client), how can I reach a database and present all his information through leaflet/shiny/R (pop up)

Tags: input, shiny, leaflet, reactive

I have a database organized with 5 columns: `client_name`, `client id`, `city`, `latitude`, and `longitude`.

I would like to create a shiny app, where the user can select a client by `id` and then see a map with a marker showing the client's location and a pop up with their main information

The code below lets the user select a client and shows a map, but the map always appears with the marker at the default latitude and longitude (45 and 3).

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinythemes)

ee <- read.csv(file="C:\\Shiny\\data\\comptes.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";", encoding="UTF-8")
LAT=45
LONG=3

shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

    subset_data = reactive({
        LAT= head(subset(ee,ee$client_id==input$client,  select=c(Lat)),1)
        LONG= head(subset(ee,ee$client_id==input$client, select=c(Long)),1)
        return (LAT)
        return (LONG)
    })

    #Carte vue d'ensemble
    outpu$mymap=renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>% 
        addMarkers(lng=LONG, lat=LAT, popup="XXXX")
    })
})

shinyUI(navbarPage("Title",
    theme = shinytheme("united"),
    tabPanel("Vue d'ensemble",
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                textInput("client","Votre id client")
            ),
            mainPanel(
                width=8,
                leafletOutput('mymap')
            )
        )
)))
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Hard to tell what might be going wrong without a bit of data. Can you provide a sample of your database to help with testing?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you never return and access your updated `LAT` and `LONG` values. There are two problems:

First, you can only return one thing from a function. In your `subset_data` function, when your code reaches `return(LAT)` it returns that value and never reaches `return(LONG)`. If you want to return 2 values from one function, you should make them into a list or vector and return that:

```
subset_data = reactive({
    LAT= head(subset(ee,ee$client_id==input$client,  select=c(Lat)),1)
    LONG= head(subset(ee,ee$client_id==input$client, select=c(Long)),1)
    return(c('LAT' = LAT, 'LONG' = LONG)))
})
```

Second, you don't access your reactive expression correctly. `LAT` and `LONG` are set at the beginning and never changed. The `subset_data` function is never run and, even if it was, it will **NOT** change the values of the global variables `LAT` and `LONG`. The way you use `reactive` expressions is to call them when you need to access their values.

In this case, when you want to get the value of `LAT` and `LONG`, you call the `subset_data` function  which then checks to see if the inputs it relies on have been changed and returns its value. Since the value is a named vector, you can access your desired value using double bracket notation `[[]]`:

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>% 
        addMarkers(lng=subset_data()[['LONG']], lat=subset_data()[['LAT']], popup="XXXX")
})
```